# XMLRPC System Multicall and BruteForce

Tags: xml-rpc

So when we perform the brute force in XMLRPC using the `wp.getUserBlogs`, while we have user but not the corresponding password. It says that there is implemented method where `system.multicall` allows single fail authentication. It means while attacker tries 100 of passwords in one shot, only a single credential is validated and if it fails, the rest of following credentials automatically fails.

I just want to know that if they fail with same status code/ error or different one. Because the attacker doesn't know if it is false positive or actual brute forcing is happening.

Also, is this a valid vulnerability if the attacker can perform brute force at WordPress without knowing what's happening behind the picture, because they only see the response to be 200 ok from the server for each of the request.

Also would like to know in which version this `system.multicall` is implemented in this way.

Comment: usually we have a 1 question per question policy, I've tried to break what you wrote up into paragraphs to make it easier to read but it's still difficult to parse. If you can edit to improve the readability, as well as include links to where you saw the things you referenced that would be super helpful. Remember you need to phrase your question in such a way that you can mark a submitted answer as correct, this isn't a discussion forum